# Show different View Data in view with different class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, view, actionresult, viewdata

This is my controller:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult>ActiveEmailAccount(EmailActiveAccountViewModel active)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {
            var result = await _userService.ActiveAccount(active);
            switch (result)
            {
                case ActiveEmailResult.Error:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Have Error ");
                    break;

                case ActiveEmailResult.NotActive:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Are not Active. ");
                    break;

                case ActiveEmailResult.Success:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Are Active ");
                 
                    break;
            }

            ViewData["Active"] = result;
        }

        return View(active);

}
```

I want to show result of View data in view.
I know it is

```
<p> @(ViewData["Active"] </P>
```

I want to know how can I show these results in different status with different class?

for example if was success: with class="alert-success"

if was not active with class alert-danger.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the switch-case statement in your action you can set a `ViewData` entry with the alert class for each case:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ActiveEmailAccount(EmailActiveAccountViewModel active)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _userService.ActiveAccount(active);

        switch (result)
        {
            case ActiveEmailResult.Error:
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Have Error ");
                ViewData["AlertClass"] = "alert-danger";
                break;

            case ActiveEmailResult.NotActive:
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Are not Active. ");
                ViewData["AlertClass"] = "alert-warning";
                break;

            case ActiveEmailResult.Success:
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "You Are Active ");
                ViewData["AlertClass"] = "alert-success";
                break;
        }

        // this is not needed for this scenario
        //ViewData["Active"] = result;
    }

    return View(active);
}
```

Then in your view you can use `Html.ValidationMessage` html helper to get the model state message and `ViewData` to get the alert class:

```html
<div class="alert @ViewData["AlertClass"]">
    @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
</div>
```

**Razor solution:**

You can use a switch-case statement inside your view:

```
@switch ((ActiveEmailResult)ViewData["Active"])
{
    case ActiveEmailResult.Error:
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")</div>
        break;

    case ActiveEmailResult.NotActive:
        <div class="alert alert-warning">@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")</div>
        break;

    case ActiveEmailResult.Success:
        <div class="alert alert-success">@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")</div>
        break;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, ActiveEmailResult has 3 result, i want to know , how should i check it on view, my view has @model AryanITC.Domain.ViewModels.Account.EmailActiveAccountViewModel

Comment: @Dimitris_Maragkos it works , but I have a question. if i control it in Controller, should I control it on view too? and in this case , how about error massage in controller? i want to show that message on controller exactly

Comment: it doesn't work again. I know, I had to cast view data ? But because I am problem in concept of view data, I don't know how can I cast it ? and how can I compare it on view?

Comment: You don't need to cast anything if you follow the method I'm showing above. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @dimitris_maragkos   @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
it work with this code and show exactly that message on enum result, but I want to show message with different class, for example if was success show in class success class, if error , show with danger class... like it.

Comment: In the controller switch-case statement I'm setting the appropriate alert class in `ViewData["AlertClass"]`. Then using `ViewData["AlertClass"]` in the `div`. Did you add that?

Comment: yes it doesn't work , as I said, It has just 0ne class, I have 3 result , so I want  to show , 3 message  with 3 class

Comment: It works and here is an example: https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO73752000

Comment: @dimitris_maragkos Thanks so much , I understand if I use ViewData, its youranswer, and I can use ViewBag and TempData, right? which one is better?

Comment: Check this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1

Comment: @dimitris_Maragkos please tell me how can I cast the viewdata , if it was enumresult. for example now, ViewData["Active"] = result , how can I cast it ? I mean its syntax and cast?/

Comment: `@if((ActiveEmailResult)ViewData["Active"] == ActiveEmailResult.Error) { ... }`